# Can I change eclipse theme to look like netbeans?

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, themes

Can I change the eclipse theme to look like netbeans? I've tried to change the font, but it didn't look similar.

Comment: Yea interesting question. Also I would be interested in an option of a quick import of short-cut keys from NetBeans, like formatting code, sorting out imports, etc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Eclipse Color Themes](http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/) has many color themes, including this one for [Netbeans 7.0](http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=theme&id=700).

Comment: @Richard: how do i use it?